# Speedup in execution time using Amdahl's law

Tags: performance, microprocessors, cpu-speed, parallelism-amdahl

I have been given this problem in one of my assignments. I understand the principles of the process of speedup, execution time etc.. However, I feel that this question is incomplete. Is it true or can it be solved? If so can you please explain.

A program executes on the original version of a machine that runs at a 2GHz clock rate. The program takes 450 micro-seconds of CPU time.  An improvement is made to the machine that affects 80% of the code in the program.  Based on Amdahl’s law, this improvement would yield an N% speedup in the execution time for the program. What value is N?   Express your answer to two decimal places.